# Increasing version and build number automatically in kotlin projects

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, fastlane

I want to automatically increase the version and build number in my kotlin projects. For my iOS applications, fastlane solves my problem with the plugin it offers. but I don't know how to do this in my android projects. maybe there is a gradle plugin? can you help me

Answer (score 1):

I like [ReactiveCircus/app-versioning](https://github.com/ReactiveCircus/app-versioning). It reads Git tags to set Android's `versionCode` and `versionName`. The default behavior works great and you may create custom rules if needed.